# What Are Large Graphs? What is Large Graph Analysis? What Is Big Data? What is Big Data Analysis?

Tags: graph, analysis, bigdata

I know what are these as I have started working with them. But for now, I just want to know the formal definitions of these terms and questions.

Any help in these regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is no absolute, formal criterion of when a graph becomes 'large' of when the amount of data becomes 'big'. These adjectives are meaningless without a frame of reference.

For instance, when you say someone is 'tall', it is implicitly assumed that you are either comparing this person to yourself, or to a perceived average height of people. If you change your frame of reference and compare this person to, let's say Mount Everest, this person's height becomes negligible. I could give a billion other examples, but the take-home message is: there is no absolute notion of 'bigness' or 'smallness'. The notion of scale is a *relative* notion. Simple concept, but with very strong implication: in a sense, physics has been so successful because physicists understood it very early.

So, to answer this question, I think a good of thumb is:

- 'large graphs' are graphs the exploration of which require long computation times on a typical quad-core machine compared to what people judge reasonable (an hour, a day. Your patience may vary).
- 'big data' are typically data which take too much memory space to be stored on a single hard drive.

Of course these are just rules of thumbs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually A graph that has a set of nodes and arrows is a Small graph; otherwise, it is a Large graph. 
If we show collection of nodes of a graph G by G0 and the collection of arrows by G1 then let G0= {1,2}, G1= {a,b,c}, 
source(a) = target(a) = source(b) = target(c)=1 and target(b) = source(c) = 2. It is small graph but The graph of sets and functions has all sets as nodes and all functions between sets as arrows. The source of a function is its domain, and its target is its codomain. 
In this example, unlike the previous ones, the nodes do not form a set.Thus the graph of sets and functions is a large graph.
 More generally we refer to any kind of mathematical structure as ‘small’ if the collection(s) it is built on form sets, and ‘large’ otherwise.